# htaccess redirect url with variable to only one URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

can you help me how to redirect a url like this: myurl.com/targi/get/-VARIABLE- (for example:  "myurl.com/targi/get/1234") to one defined page:
http://www.myurl.com/artykuly/1?q=&kat=wydarzenia

I have tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} targi/get/(.*)
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://website.com/se/category/%1? [L,R=301]
```

But it won't work :/

Comment: **targi/get/1234** is an url path not a query string.

Comment: Can you help me what I have to change? I am a newbie at htaccess

Answer (score 0):

To redirect

- http://www.myurl.com/targi/get/1234

to

- http://www.myurl.com/artykuly/1?q=&kat=wydarzenia

You can use this rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^targi/get/[0-9]+/?$ http://www.myurl.com/artykuly/1?q=&kat=wydarzenia [L,R,NC]
```

Comment: I have added this to my htaccess but redirect don't work.